# Cual es la mejor manera de almacenar un jCheckBox en mysql java netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

tengo la siguiente duda, estoy necesitando almacenar los campos de jCheckBox según el cliente los utilice, pero no tengo idea de como almacenarlos de una manera correcta en MySQL, y tampoco se como seria el INSERT correcto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es ***como deberia crear las columnas en la tabla sql***,(caracteristicas y configuraciones para que almacene el verdadero o falso). **Y la otra como insertarlo desde java**.
En el INSERT to tengo el siguiente que tambien ingreso otros datos como ticket y tambien id:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Ticket(IDCLIENTE,TICKET) VALUES('" + tfId.getText() + "','" + tfTicket.getText() + "')");
```

@Sal Gracias por tu aporte, estoy teniendo el siguiente problema al adaptar tu codigo:

```
    private void jCheckFuenteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    List<JCheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
    for (Opcion opc : Opcion.values()) {
        JCheckBox chk = new JCheckBox("DEJA " + opc.name());
        chk.setName(opc.name()); // El nombre ayuda a saber cuál >> esta opcion no entiendo para que es?? opcion
        jCheckFuente.add(chk);
        jCheckBateria.add(chk);
        jCheckFunda.add(chk);
        contenedor.add(chk);  // Tu panel
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para estos casos la utilidad del tipo `SET` (Conjunto):

```
ALTER TABLE Ticket ADD deja SET('FUENTE','BATERIA','FUNDA','MOUSE');
-- Nótesen lo valores:           --1---   ---2---   --4--   --8--
```

De tal manera que a cada checkbox le das el valor de cada elemento del conjunto; incluso podrías/deberías crear un correspondiente Java Enum a partir del mismo conjunto:

```
public enum Opcion{
    FUENTE(1), BATERIA(2), FUNDA(4), MOUSE(8);
    
    private final int n;
      
    Opcion(int n){ this.n = n; }
    
    public int getCodigo(){ return this.n; }      
}
```

A partir del cual puedes crear las casillas de selección, y mantener una referencia única en -por ejemplo- una lista:

```
List<JCheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
for( Opcion opc : Opcion.values() ){
    JCheckBox chk = new JCheckBox("DEJA "+opc.name());
    chk.setName(opc.name()); // El nombre ayuda a saber cuál opcion
    checkboxes.add( chk );
    contenedor.add( chk );  // Tu panel
}
```

Para saber cuáles fueron las opciones seleccionadas:

```
int suma = 0;
for( JCheckBox chk : checkboxes )
    if( chk.isSelected() )
        suma += Opcion.valueOf(chk.getName()).getCodigo();
        
System.out.println("=>"+suma);
```

Por ejemplo, si selecciona Bateria (2) y Mouse (8), la suma de los valores de selección es 10.

Al persistir en MySQL, guardas en la columna esa suma:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( 
    "INSERT INTO Ticket(IDCLIENTE,TICKET,deja) 
         VALUES(?,?,?)"
);
ps.setString(1,tfId.getText());
ps.setString(2,tfTicket.getText());
ps.setInt(3,suma);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Lo mas divertido, es que al hacer la consulta obtienes los valores del conjunto:

```
mysql> SELECT deja FROM Tickets;
+---------------+
| deja          |
+---------------+
| BATERIA,MOUSE |
+---------------+
```

Algunos querrán quemar en leña verde a los ingenieros de MySQL, por ser herejes de la normalización; pero la realidad nos sugiere que es una solución muy conveniente cuando tienes un conjunto de datos:

- bien definido
- reducido
- que casi no cambie con el paso del tiempo

Comment: Hola SAL, muchas gracias por lo que me comentas, pero creo que el ALTER TABLE seria para modificar? porque lo que yo necesito es agregar el contenido nuevo a la tabla. 
Lo que genero es un ticket de soporte tecnico informatico, y esos check box lo utilizare para saber si el cliente dejo o no eso que esta marcado, por ejemplo una bateria, o una fuente etc.

Comment: La idea es crear una sola columna para todos los booleanos, el `ALTER` es para crear esa columna.

Comment: Realmente interesante. No conocía el uso del `set` en mysql, pero lo veo realmente util, buena respuesta y excelentemente explicada y argumentada!

Comment: Bueno la verdad que se ve super explicado, pero realmente me supera lo he leido muchas veces, y nose por donde comenzar a editar el codigo para hacerlo funcionar como me indicas.

Comment: El `enum` lo puedes colocar en un `.java` por separado. En algún lugar -que no conozco- de tu código has de instanciar los componentes, mientras que en otro manejas algún evento del usuario para enviar a la base de datos. No necesitas manejar el `ActionPerformed` de los cuadros de selección. Y donde el IDE suplica por el  operador diamante quita el genérico : `new ArrayList<>()`.